# Pygtk - Liststore, Remove the last row

Tags: python, pygtk

how could I remove the last row of a liststore?

I have this code running before deleting the last row:

```
  iter = self.model_add.insert(0, ["Hi", "Hello", "Python", "World!"])
  iter = self.model_add.insert(1, ["Hi2", "Hello2", "Python2", "World!2"])
```

I'd like to remove the second one row, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
self.model_add.remove(self.model_add[-1].iter)
```

You need a `gtk.TreeIter` to remove a row. Indexing a model (for example, with `-1` to get the last row) gives you a `gtk.TreeModelRow`, and its `iter` attribute is a `gtk.TreeIter` pointing to that row.

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit - this answer showed up in the "low quality posts".

Comment: Sure, I didn't know that could even happen! I kept it succinct because it didn't seem like the questioner had shown much research effort, but you're right, that's not my call.